# Created By Color-coding calendar

Tags: 2013, calendar

Is there a way to do the color coding by the field "Created by"
I mean if the user A creates an event the color of the event will be Blue but if the user B creates an event the color of the event will be Green. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below mentioned link to change color code of calendar events.

https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/color-code-events-on-a-sharepoint-calendar/

In above link, they display to differentiate the category of events. you can change the column from category to Created By in filter of the view.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Include the essential parts of the link in your answer and use the link as a source. This way your answer will still be helpful even if the link breaks.

Comment: @Hardik I agree with Robert. Thank you anyway for your answer :) you are right!